# DBus introspection object tree using dbus-send

Tags: bash, dbus

Is it possible to gather the complete object tree of a DBus connection name using dbus-send?

Currently I am able to do this performing multiple calls to the desired destination specifying the method 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect' and using '/' as path the first time, than retrieving the inner nodes and performing a new call on those.

For example:

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Bluetooth.applet / org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect

gives nodes Factory and org. So I proceed with the calls:

$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Bluetooth.applet /Factory org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect

$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Bluetooth.applet /org org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect

and so on...
```

I would like to retrive the complete tree at once.

I know tools like d-feet can do this, but I need a cli interface and dbus-send would be very handy.

Comment: I have found a possible "one shot solution", at least for my needs:   gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gnome.Bluetooth.applet --object-path / --recurse --xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can ask bus to list all service names, but there is no way to ask all interfaces, so usually there are two scenarios: 1) You know interface names and use them 2) you start with `/` and process recursively based on `Introspect()` responses. D-feet does (2)

Answer (score 3):

`busctl` is a handy tool for interacting with DBus

Give this a try :

```
busctl tree
```